# What changes need to be made in the Startup file to enable owin to work natively in IIS virtual directory without having to hardcode the path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, owin, identityserver3

I have been working with the Thinktecture IdentityServer3 Asp.Net Identity WebHost sample project.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/AspNetIdentity

A portion of the startup class will be pasted below. The project compiles fine after pulling back the more recent nuget repos, however, I deployed it in a virtual directory in IIS and realized, that I am unable to contact any of the Owin modules. I am learning Owin but not quickly enough. I realize that this is probably something basic and related to request matching with app.map, and I have tried the basics:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn448010(v=vs.113).aspx

[How are OwinContext.Request.Path and PathBase populated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648722/how-are-owincontext-request-path-and-pathbase-populated)

but I can not get to the OWIN modules from a virtual directory. When I created a new website and deployed the project to the root, the project worked without issue (after some changes to the sqlconnection string) and I can reach all pages.

**My question is how to use app.map to match with the request when the application is deployed in IIS virtual directory
Application Works Great at Root - http://localhost:8080
Requests do not seem to hit/match the OWIN paths in virtual directory - http://localhost/idsrvrtest
.**

```
 namespace WebHost
 {
     public class Startup
     {
      public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        LogProvider.SetCurrentLogProvider(new DiagnosticsTraceLogProvider());
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
           .MinimumLevel.Debug()
           .WriteTo.Trace()
           .CreateLogger();
        Debug.WriteLine("Owin is working");
        app.Map( "/admin", adminApp =>
        {
            var factory = new IdentityManagerServiceFactory();
            factory.ConfigureSimpleIdentityManagerService("AspId");
            //factory.ConfigureCustomIdentityManagerServiceWithIntKeys("AspId_CustomPK");

            adminApp.UseIdentityManager(new IdentityManagerOptions()
            {
                Factory = factory
            });
        });
```

Comment: I am guessing based on the lack of response, that my question may not have merrit. All comments and suggestions welcome.

Comment: This is really bizarre. I tried changing the app.map to app.MapWhen and then even the base url's (admin/core) do not work. The sample only seems to work when I use app.map as configured in the sample project. However, as far as I can tell there isn't a dependency in the sample project.

Comment: I'm no longer certain it's an app.match problem. After playing with the solution for hours and testing different configurations it's looking like being hosted at the website root is a requirement. Can someone confirm?

Comment: Are you trying to hit /admin whilst deployed to IIS virtual directory /idsrvrtest? If that's the case the above code would only allow for /idsrvrtest/admin.

Comment: Agreed. I tried that also after this post, the result is that I do not get a 404 but I also do not get content. The sample project works great as long as it's deployed as its own site. Does not seem to work for me under any sub path. I also tried changing app.map to app.map"/idsrvrtest/admin". No luck.